# How to get the item in the dynamo db which match particular key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

- I have dynamo db, `user` as `partition_key` and time as `sort_key`
- I need to extract from dynamodb where `user=abc@gmail.com` and `message=192.168.1.1`

Using filter `Attr`, I can extract with key and value

`table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr("message").eq("192.168.1.1"))`

Now how to extract for particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two primary ways to fetch data in DynamoDB; `scan` and `query`

The `query` operation can be used to fetch an item(s) when the partition key is known.  The `scan` operation returns one or more items by searching the *entire* database.  As you might guess, the `query` operation is preferred over the `scan` operation because it's a more performant operation.

In your example, the partition key is known.  Therefore, you should be using the `query` operation to fetch the data you are after.  The operation should look something like this

```
table.query( {
        "TableName": "YOUR TABLE NAME HERE",
        "KeyConditionExpression": "#user = :user",
        "FilterExpression": "#message = :message",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#user":"user","#message":"message"},
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":user": {"S":"abc@gmail.com"},":message": {"S":"192.168.1.1"}}
    })
```